# Stopping an update from happening more than once, consecutively

Tags: c#, xna

I'm making a pong game.

When the ball strikes either of the paddles it triggers a sound effect. The problem however, is that XNA updates 60 fps. Therefore, sometimes I'll hear the faint sound of the my sfx trigger just starting to go off during the initial collision.

I'd like to make it so that the SFX triggers goes off once, and then not occurring again until :
A) The ball scores 
or
B) The ball collides with the opposite bat.

What is the best approach I can take to do something like this?

Here is what my trigger currently looks like, in my ball class:

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Draws a rectangle where the ball and bat collide. Also triggers the SFX for when they collide
    /// </summary>
    private void BatCollisionRectLeft()
    {
        // For the left bat
        if (ballRect.Intersects(leftBat.batRect))
        {
            rectangle3 = Rectangle.Intersect(ballRect, leftBat.batRect);
            hasHitLeftBat = true;
            lastHitLeftBat = true;
            lasthitRightBat = false;
            AudioManager.Instance.PlaySoundEffect("hit2");
            Speed += .2f;            // Gradually increases the ball's speed each time it connects with the bat
        }
    }
```

That function is then called within my ball's update function, which is called by the main gameplay class in XNA.

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Updates position of the ball. Used in Update() for GameplayScreen.
    /// </summary>
    public void UpdatePosition(GameTime gameTime)
    {
              .......

    // As long as the ball is to the right of the back, check for an update
        if (ballPosition.X > leftBat.BatPosition.X)
        {
            // When the ball and bat collide, draw the rectangle where they intersect
            BatCollisionRectLeft();
        }

        // As long as the ball is to the left of the back, check for an update
        if (ballPosition.X < rightBat.BatPosition.X)

        {   // When the ball and bat collide, draw the rectangle where they intersect
            BatCollisionRectRight();
        }
                     ........
              }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a boolean variable indicating the previous state of collision.

> If myPreviousCollisionState = `false`, and myCurrentCollisionState = `true` ->
>   Play the sound, change direction, etc...

At the end of your update call, you can set

`myPreviousCollisionState = myCurrentCollisionState`

Obviously, at the beginning of the game, `myPreviousCollisionState = false`

With that code, your sound will only be played on the first frame of the collision.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! Clear and concise. I'l give it a try tonight, let you know how it goes, and approve as an answer as soon as I get it going!

Answer (score 1):

Solution would look something like this. This code is not tested nor functional, it's only here for the idea. Bassically you have a timer that waits for some time (ms) before it will play sound again; to play sound again your collision detection request must be meet. It's simple delay timer.

```
float timer = 0, timerInterval = 100;
bool canDoSoundEffect = true;
...
void Update(GameTime gt) {
    float delta = (float)gt.ElapsedTime.TotalMilliseconds;

    // Check if we can play soundeffect again
    if (canDoSoundEffect) {
        // Play soundeffect if collided and set flag to false
        if (ballRect.Intersects(leftBat.batRect)) {

            ... Collision logic here...

            AudioManager.Instance.PlaySoundEffect("hit2");
            canDoSoundEffect = false;
        }
    }
    // So we can't play soundeffect - it means that not enough time has passed 
    // from last play so we need to increase timer and when enough time passes, 
    // we set flag to true and reset timer
    else {
        timer += delta;
        if (timer >= timerInterval) {
            timer -= timerInterval;
            canDoSoundEffect = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the way you did this here. I'll give this a try this evening as well, and let you know how it works.

Thank you again!